# MongoDB Hybrid Cloud deployment on-premise first capable?

Tags: mongodb

We have multiple on-premises with a MongoDB instance for each and want to sync some collections between those instances.

It should also be possible to add a private cloud instance in the best case.

Some on-premise instances might be powered off for a few days or don't have access to the public internet.

If it goes online all instances should update the changes so that each instance has the latest data on its own disk.

We don't want to use MongoDB Atlas.

The sync should be done automatically.

1. Is it possible to make MongoDB work with an on-premise-first approach?
2. are replica sets a solution in this case? Is it realistic for replica sets to sync multiple days of data if one node is not accessible for that long by other nodes?